# Angular SEO using HTML Unit and prerender.io

Tags: angularjs, seo, google-search

I have Ajax heavy website which is developed using angular. I tried using HTML Unit to take care of SEO to render my pages for the bots. But HTML Unit is really slow takes almost 12 secs to render my page.
I then shifted to phantom jus based prerender.io .. The performance was better around 3secs. But phantom server crashes when loaded with 10 users for just 2 mins.

Should I really worry about response time from my SEO servers to respond to bots and what would the load from bots be in website with ~100 different pages. How many parallel request should my SEO server handle.

Is page rank dependent on response time of the bots.

Comment: Google does take response time into account.

Comment: Try saving generated pages in cache and serving those to bots. That way you control the load.

Comment: Agree with Sergiu, here the best option is probably to make cached copies of these daily or so and serve those up instead.  In terms of traffic I've not seen a ton of it from search engine bots, they have a lot of sites to index so they're generally just making their rounds every month or so it seems.  I'd say just put a tracker in there and keep your access log on for a bit to see for yourself how much the site is being hit.

Comment: Also if you haven't already enable gzip compression on the server (with Apache it's trivial and can significantly decrease payloads). One more thing to consider is minification/uglification using grunt or otherwise and concatenating files where possible.  I'm considering concating my templates even into a single HTML page.  In theory could load everything, ajax aside, in 3 or 4 requests from my server JS/HTML, CSS, Image and everything else coming from CDN.

Answer (score -3):

Google does care about response speed.

If you are serving snapshots of your pages then you should be following Google's Crawlable Ajax Specification: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/ (Bing and Yandex support this too)

Two good reasons to follow this spec are:

1) Google will understand that you are doing the rendering on the server and they are probably smart enough to understand that this means the response time will not be the normal one for your site.

2) Google wont misinterpret as nefarious the fact that you are serving general vistors one version of your page and Google another.

More info about these issues on our site: https://ajaxsnapshots.com (we provide a SaaS solution for crawlable Javascript)

Comment: why does this have so many negative votes without any comments?  Is it not a valid answer?  It certainly seems correct to me.